# Magento 2 Product Detail Page Image Not Loading

Tags: magento2

After **upgrading** Magento 2, 
The products detail page **product images** are not loading, but the product archive page thumbnails are loading or showing.

I have tried ..

- Flushing all caches
- granting permissions
- esizing images

But nothing seems to work or solve the issue. Screenshot [here](http://prntscr.com/ji64oy)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your screenshot.

You have to do the following step ----

1. At first, you have to check your browser console to see any require js issue.
2. Give permission `pub/media` folder `sudo chmod 777 -R pub/media/`

Let me know if will face any issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here's the screenshot of errors the browser is throwing: http://prntscr.com/jk9120

Comment: Reindex and compile solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2 view page
Issue with breadcrumbs file in `Magent_Catalog/templates/product/breadcrumbs.phtml`

update below code:

```
"product": "<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->escapeJsQuote($viewModel->getProductName(), '"')); ?>"
```

you can do following:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs" data-mage-init='{
    "breadcrumbs": {
        "categoryUrlSuffix": "<?= $block->escapeHtml($viewModel->getCategoryUrlSuffix()); ?>",
        "useCategoryPathInUrl": <?= (int)$viewModel->isCategoryUsedInProductUrl(); ?>,
        "product": "<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->escapeJsQuote($viewModel->getProductName(), '"')); ?>"
    }
}'>
</div>
```